# IIS Reverse Proxy Rewrite Rule usage monitoring

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

How can I display stats for each Rewrite rule in IIS when using it as a reverse proxy with ARR?
We use 'Orenosp' Secure reverse proxy for some of our networks but use IIS + ARR for others and one of the features I miss from Orenosp is the that is shows all the rules in a table and shows the hits and response stats for each rule.

I know that you can get this information for Web Farms within IIS but there is no overview for every rule.
How does everyone else monitor IIS rules when using it as a reverse proxy?

Regards
Dan